# BigInteger compareTo vs subtract + signnum()

Tags: java, biginteger

### Problem

Was trying the following possible optimization in my code.
(Update: **subtract is slower** which makes sense since it is a more complicated procedure).

Code:

```
   if (bigK.compareTo(prevLevelChildrenCount) > 0)
```

to

```
 if (bigK.subtract(prevLevelChildrenCount).signum() == 1)
```

Speed (Subtract vs compareTo) when used 100,000,000 times iteratively for random numbers.

[image]

### Question:

Is the biginteger behavior the same when using subtraction as integer in terms of overflows?

I found the following question but consider this is **not a duplicate because biginteger does not have the same limitations as integer.** But does it share the overflow issue?

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson This is for biginteger. It's not exactly a duplicate since the same limitations/conditions do not apply. Is the behavior the same in terms of overflows?

Comment: It might have been helpful if you made clear that `bigK` and `prevLevelChildrenCount` is a `BigInteger`. When you say `I am comparing two positive big integers` it's a little uncertain whether you're talking about `BigInteger` or large `int` values.

Comment: `Both` the `title`, and the `tag` include the word `BigInteger`. Will add to the code as well.

Comment: True... Just shows how blind people can be :P Sorry.

Comment: **Important:** `compareTo` doesn't have to return 1 when the left hand side exceeds the right hand side.  It only has to return a positive value.  So using `== 1` after `compareTo` is a poor idea.

Comment: @David Wallace please see my update. I currently have JDK1.6 src on this machine. Unless I'm tired..I see -1, 0, 1

Comment: You shouldn't rely on this.  What happens if you have to upgrade to a later version of Java, and the behaviour is different?  When using _any_ API, you should only rely on its documented behaviour - and the documented behaviour of `compareTo` is that it returns positive, 0 or negative in the three cases, not that it returns 1, 0 or -1.

Comment: @David Wallace Javadoc-Official Documentation: Returns -1, 0 or 1 as this BigInteger is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val. SRC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger)

Comment: @maythesource.com It's not a bad practice to use `> 0`.

Comment: True... they could just change it in another version since comparable is <0 or >0 .

Comment: I apologise.  I take it all back.  Since the doc for `BigInteger` makes this claim, it's OK to use.  I was looking at the doc for `Comparable`, which is different.  Note there is a paragraph in the doc for `BigInteger` which suggests using `> 0` or `< 0` in any case.  Regardless, what you've done is perfectly fine.

Comment: "Subtract seems to be working faster" - how did you test that? Unless you have a proper benchmark and you can explain its results properly, you are doing premature optimization on the basis of subjective observations or assumptions.

Comment: @Oleg Estekhin Thanks for reminding me. I profiled a test that iteratively called each of the two and found subtract is actually slower. Also Elliot said: "Beware of performing such micro optimizations, it's likely to vary by platform, architecture and implementation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any reason why I shouldn't do this? I am comparing two positive big integers?

I don't see why you shouldn't, make sure it works first.

> Which one should be faster? In my own tests subtract seems to work faster.

I wouldn't trust that one is faster then another universally. Beware that micro-optimization is rarely productive.

> Is the biginteger behavior the same when using subtraction as integer in terms of overflows.
>   But does it share the overflow issue?

No, [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) will not overflow. Per the linked Javadoc,

> All of the details in the Spec concerning overflow are ignored, as BigIntegers **are** made as large as necessary to accommodate the results of an operation.

Comment: So is it more efficient then using compareTo ? Or does it depend on the numbers used and which bits are set to what?

Comment: @maythesource.com Edited. Beware of performing such micro optimizations, it's likely to vary by platform, architecture and implementation. Also, micro-benchmarks are not usually reliable.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and comment. I'll go back to working on bigger algorithmic bottlenecks - got carried away.